# How To Change A Global Variable From Inside An If Statement - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement

I have put together a loop which I want to run through several times. I want to change some values each time the code completes a loop in the array defined as "num" without having the array reset to (1,2) every time the code loops.  I currently have the changes to the array that I want being made inside if/else statements in the code. I know that this is a scope issue, I just do not know how to fix it.

```
for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {

var num = new Array(1, 2);
var bet = [];
var ran = [];
var wl = [];

bet = num[0] + num[num.length - 1];
ran = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000) + 1);
if (ran <= 4637) {
    wl = "Win"
}
else {
    wl = "Lose"
}

var para = document.createElement("p");
var node = document.createTextNode(num + " | Bet:" + bet + " | " + wl);
para.appendChild(node);
var element = document.getElementById("text");
element.appendChild(para);
window.scrollBy(0,1000);

if (ran <= 4637) {
    num.splice(0,1)
    num.splice(cars.length - 1,1)
}
else {
    num.push(bet)
}

}
```

Comment: Easy fix is to put it the variable that you do not want to have defined over and over again out of your loop or use a closure

Comment: @Mikey That is all I needed. I feel like an idiot now. Have been trying to fix this for at least an hour now. Still in the early stages of learning.

Comment: That is cool. That is how we al start :)...I would highly recommend to look into closures and object oriented programming in javascript when you get through the basics